# python Attribute error. Im not sure what is causing this. Is it because my web cam not recogonized?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing

I just began to learn image processing using python 3.5, in Ubuntu. As I began to learning processing video using the webcam I got stuck with an AttributeError. error is module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'Videocapture'

the code I used is

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.Videocapture(0)
while True:
     ret,frame = cap.read()
     cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
     if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
         break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried googling your error message? Which of the suggested solutions have you tried and why didn't they work?

Comment: i think the problem is in the default version of python3 in ubuntu. Which is python 3.5.2

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, the object is called `cv2.VideoCapture` (note the capital `C`) and Python is case-sensitive.